# Is it possible to define key macros without the equality sign (i.e., [keya=value])

Tags: macros, key-value, xkeyval

I was wondering if the xkeyval package allows for defining key macros **which do not** include an equality symbol.

For instance, I wish to create a package based on the geometry package with the following key definitions:

**the *default* parameter:** margin=1cm,

***keya* (overrides the default)**: margin=2cm,

***keyb* (additional parameter)**: showframe,

Can one define Macros so that:

```
\usepackage[keya,keyb]{mygeo}
```

would produce:

```
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{keya,keyb}
```

Without having to write:

```
\usepackage[keya=1cm,keyb]{mygeo}
```

Basic and incomplete MWE structure:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{mygeo}
%
\DeclareOption{keya}{}
\DeclareOption{keyb}{}
\DeclareOption*{\PackageWarning{mygeo}{Unknown ‘\CurrentOption’}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
%
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{keya,keyb}
```

Comment: Can you please describe what you're trying to achieve? Why do you need that wrapper package? Why do you need several different keys that should just forward options to `geometry`? Wouldn't one key suffice for that purpose? And is that really easier than just loading `geometry` with the desired options? An MWE that is a bit closer to the actual use case would be better here.

Comment: Since I produce a lot of TeX files, I have constructed a bash code that produces a ready made folder and files for different settings (for example, letter, presentation etc..) . The parameters of the geometry package I load are far lengthier than the MWE, therefore, it would save a lot of lines of codes to prepare a package which is designed to several purposes, and would be configured by one or two key values. Moreover, I intend to apply the solution to this problem for several packages I use for the same purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** I've added a new answer that uses a key=value interface, and allows forwarding values that contain a comma. If this isn't necessary for your use, take a look at the original answer at the bottom.

## New Answer

If you need a key=value interface and want to be able to pass arguments containing commas to the underlying keys, you'll need an up to date LaTeX installation, because the relevant feature (raw option lists) were added on 2021-06-01. The parsing of that list isn't yet supported by many packages, to the best of my knowledge as of writing this only `expkv-opt` really supports this).

The result is that you'll have to change your key=val interface, and use [`expkv`](https://texdoc.net/serve/expkv/0) [and](https://texdoc.net/serve/expkv-def/0) [its](https://texdoc.net/serve/expkv-cs/0) [family](https://texdoc.net/serve/expkv-opt/0) instead of `xkeyval`. The following defines your basic keys using the interface provided by [`expkv-def`](https://texdoc.net/serve/exkpv-def/0), and parses your package options using [`expkv-opt`](https://texdoc.net/serve/expkv-opt/0).

*Disclaimer: I'm the author of the `expkv` family of packages.*

```
\begin{filecontents}{mygeo.sty}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{mygeo}
%
\PassOptionsToPackage{margin=1cm}{geometry}
\RequirePackage{expkv-opt,expkv-def}
\ekvdefinekeys{morzen}
  {
    % code will be executed when the key is called
     protected code    keya  = \PassOptionsToPackage{#1}{geometry}
    % sets the argument #1 in above code if no value is given
    ,default           keya  = margin=2cm
    % noval will be executed when the key is called, the key doesn't accept
    % values
    ,protected noval   keyb  = \PassOptionsToPackage{showframe}{geometry}
    % will be used if an undefined key with a value is found
    ,protected unknown code  =
      \PackageWarning{mygeo}
        {Unknown option `#1' you passed `\detokenize{#2}' to}
    % will be used if an undefined key without a value is found
    ,protected unknown noval = \PackageWarning{mygeo}{Unknown option `#1'}
  }
\ekvoProcessLocalOptions{morzen}
%
\RequirePackage{geometry}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[]{article}

%\usepackage{mygeo}
%\usepackage[keya]{mygeo}
%\usepackage[keya,keyb]{mygeo}
\usepackage[keya={headsep=1cm,headheight=1cm},keyb]{mygeo}

\begin{document}
This is a document.
\end{document}
```

---

## Original Answer

You don't need `xkeyval` if your question is only about translating options of package A to other options of package B (you'll need some key=value parser package however, if your package should support key=value options):

```
\begin{filecontents}{mygeo.sty}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{mygeo}
%
\PassOptionsToPackage{margin=1cm}{geometry} % setting the default margin
\DeclareOption{keya}{\PassOptionsToPackage{margin=2cm}{geometry}}
\DeclareOption{keyb}{\PassOptionsToPackage{showframe}{geometry}}
\DeclareOption*{\PackageWarning{mygeo}{Unknown ‘\CurrentOption’}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
%
\RequirePackage{geometry}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[keya,keyb]{mygeo}

\begin{document}
This is a document.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry. I simplified my problem and forgot to mention a crucial detail. The macros contain parameters separated by commas. i.e., keya=headsep=1cm, 
headheight=1cm,

Comment: @Morzen that would be possible with `expkv-opt` and an up to date LaTeX (necessary feature was added to the LaTeX kernel on 2021-06-01). But it would require braces around the argument of `keya` to hide the commas. Is that fine? If so, I'll post an answer.

Comment: Is it is fine. It will answer the question.

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I looking for, and extremely efficient. Cheers.